# Python Selenium - ChromeDriver ( Reduce GUI to increase speed )

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Okay I'm trying to get my process in Selenium running as fast as possible, it currently sends one request per second, however I'm looking to send requests quicker.

I've disabled images from loading using,

```
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
```

which increased the speed slightly enough to reach 1 second per request. Looking for other solutions in reducing speed, such as removing address bar, removing chromes visibility, disabling css etc.. I need suggestions & solutions, as there is so much unnecessary loading on the page for what i'm doing.

I've tried using other routines but due to the fact it's ran in JScript, i'm unable to send httpwebrequests using c# or something. I think it's using xmlrequests.

Comment: One thing I've done in the past is to have the code open multiple browsers so I could divide the work up between browser instances, but not sure if this is well-suited for your situation.

Comment: That would actually be a good idea however complicated with the threading and dividing requests, so the same isn't repeated.

Comment: Some problems are easier to handle with this approach than others. Not sure in your case. I believe in the past I have opened four browsers and divided my work between them. This greatly sped up my program. I hope it works for you, too.